# How to add dynamic dimension to tensor in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am having a `input_node` with shape `(None, 80, 3)` meaning `(sample_length, resolution, channel)`. However, this tensor is missing a fourth dimension for the batches. Is there a way to reshape `input_node` to `(None, None, 80, 3)`?

---

Using `tf.expand_dims` I won't be able to work with batches:

```py
wave_input = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None], name='wave_input')
encoded_dict = problem.preprocess_example({'waveforms': wave_input, 'targets': [0]}, mode, hparams)

# This is where a dynamic shape would be required
encoded_dict['inputs'] = tf.expand_dims(encoded_dict['inputs'], 0)
encoded_dict['targets'] = tf.expand_dims(encoded_dict['targets'], 0)

# Get input/output nodes

inferred = model.infer(encoded_dict)

tf.identity(encoded_dict['inputs'], name=input_name)
tf.identity(inferred['outputs'], name=output_name)
```

Comment: You can always reshape it to `(1, None, 80, 3)`, or use `tf.expand_dims` that is. But I'm not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: @jdehesa I don't think this is going to work. I know I could use `tf.expand_dims` but that would not allow me to work with batches.

Comment: But what is this `input_node`? If it is a placeholder, you can just add the dimension to the placeholder shape. If it is not, I'm not sure how (and why) you want to make a tensor bigger than it is. I mean you can use `tf.tile` or whatever but again I don't think that is what you are thinking of.

Comment: @jdehesa Hm, so the thing is this: I am loading a quantized model which I cannot re-load using the framework I am working with (tensor2tensor). This is why I am trying to add two additional nodes to the graph: `input_name` and `output_name`. Those two nodes will be used later in order to evaluate the model. However, the way I have it now - using `tf.expand_dims` - I won't be able to run batches but only one sample at a time. I added the relevant code to my question.